# Cannot remove a repository that complains it has no public key

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS, 64 bit, into 3 desktop PC (Intel i5 and i7) and 4 laptops (Intel Pentium). All with 8 GB of RAM.

Since about a week ago, I've been getting the following message each time I try to update/upgrade the system:

```
https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease" has no Public Key. It isn't safe to use this kind of repository.
```

I tried to remove that repository (which I don't remember adding) with the terminal command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r <repository to  remove>
```

But, even though the system seems to perform that action, the repository is used next time I type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This repository isn't visible in Synaptic Software Manager and/or Ubuntu Software Center.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The linked question has little to do with this one, especially if you compare the answers.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the `sources.list` file directly and either remove or comment out (probably the better solution). The sources file should be located at `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

See also the Official Ubuntu documentation on [package repository configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/configuration.html).