# E: The repository 'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management

```
Ign:1 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main zesty InRelease 
Err:2 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main zesty Release 503 Service Unavailable 
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease 
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB] 
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB] 
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease [89.2 kB] 
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [52.7 kB] 
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [26.3 kB] 
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [171 kB] 
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [223 kB] 
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,840 B] 
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,140 B] 
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.5 kB] 
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [11.6 kB] 
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [20.7 kB] 
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [36.5 kB] 
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 B] 
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Modify the file file `etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out the line `https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main zesty Release` - see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/837099/cannot-remove-a-repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837099/cannot-remove-a-repository)

Comment: That line is not in my sources.list file. The link below is a jpg image of sources.list

Comment: https://orasi365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/greg_azar_orasi_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=090103e501a464c5ba2c00d652e3230f7&authkey=ARfKT9R_XlTpH_5CgMq0lLU

Comment: @GregAzar can you share screen shot of System Settings >> Software and Updates >> Other Software.

Comment: No GUI, console only.

Comment: You may find that line in a sub file, in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server at `https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main` is down. Try again later.

If you like, you can temporarily comment out this line like so...

```
cd /etc/apt
grep download.01.org sources.list
```

**If it DOES find download.01.org there, then...**

```
sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

and comment out the line that contains download.01.org with a # at the beginning of that line.

**If it DOES NOT find download.01.org, then...**

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
grep download.01.org *.list
#note the filename that it finds
sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list.d/{enter filename here}
sudo apt-get update
```

and comment out the line that contains download.01.org with a # at the beginning of that line.